# How do I add more images to my cb-slideshow?

Tags: css, slideshow

The slides work for **images 1-6** (original code), but I need **13 images** to display. Here is what I did and thought it would work, but it doesn't. It still only plays the **first 6 images**. Originally the **70s were 36s**. I don't know what I am doing wrong/missing??

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 70s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/6.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/7.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
    -o-animation-delay: 36s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
    animation-delay: 36s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/8.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
    -o-animation-delay: 42s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
    animation-delay: 42s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(9) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/9.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 48s;
    -o-animation-delay: 48s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 48s;
    animation-delay: 48s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(10) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/10.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 54s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 54s;
    -o-animation-delay: 54s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 54s;
    animation-delay: 54s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(11) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/11.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
    -o-animation-delay: 60s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
    animation-delay: 60s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(12) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/12.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 64s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 64s;
    -o-animation-delay: 64s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 64s;
    animation-delay: 64s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(13) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/slides/13.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 70s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 70s;
    -o-animation-delay: 70s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 70s;
    animation-delay: 70s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
    -o-animation-delay: 36s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
    animation-delay: 36s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
    -o-animation-delay: 42s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
    animation-delay: 42s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(9) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 48s;
    -o-animation-delay: 48s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 48s;
    animation-delay: 48s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(10) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 54s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 54s;
    -o-animation-delay: 54s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 54s;
    animation-delay: 54s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(11) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
    -o-animation-delay: 60s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
    animation-delay: 60s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(12) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 64s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 64s;
    -o-animation-delay: 64s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 64s;
    animation-delay: 64s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(13) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 70s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 70s;
    -o-animation-delay: 70s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 70s;
    animation-delay: 70s; 
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Animation for the title */
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing it this way. I would rather use img in the html directly and maybe use a slider like caroufredsel.

Comment: Where's the HTML for the page with your slideshow? Have you defined the extra `span` and `div` elements?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML to verify, I would bet that you are missing the extra `li`, `span` and `div` elements needed to go beyond the original six.

You should have a total of 13 `li` elements with `span` and `div` elements defined for each.

You may also want to clear your cache...just in case. ;)

Comment: I did add the li to the ul
            <li><span>Image 07</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 08</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 09</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 10</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 11</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 12</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 13</span></li>

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but you just in case someone uses cb-slideshow and has the same issue...

If you change the number of images and/or the duration, you will have to adjust the ***keyframes titleAnimation*** values accordingly, as mentioned in the original article:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/